# Altcoin Wallet Warning: Virus Alert Coinstealer in it! Why?

Tags: wallet, altcoin, compiling, bitcoin-qt-setup, virus

I have compiled this Altcoin completetly from Source:

https://github.com/globaltoken/globaltoken

After i got a Compiled .exe File I uploaded it to Virustotal.
The Result was nothing, Clean Wallet :)

Some days later i checked again the same file and got this:

[image: Coinstealer??]

Why does it shows Coinstealer now?
The Source Code is based on Bitcoin and is visible on Github, where should this Files be in Source what are infected an includes "Coinstealer"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

its sounds like a false positive,the same was happened on Bitcoin core https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1694796.0 to be sure you have to options 1 check their source for backdor etc,2 or raise an issue on GitHub